# How to position custom button controls on Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've this simple map built on Google Maps APi v3 ....

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {



      var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


      //### Add a button on Google Maps ...
      var controlMarkerUI = document.createElement('DIV');
      controlMarkerUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      controlMarkerUI.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://localhost/marker.png)";
      controlMarkerUI.style.height = '28px';
      controlMarkerUI.style.width = '25px';
      controlMarkerUI.style.top = '11px';
      controlMarkerUI.style.left = '120px';
      controlMarkerUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
      //myLocationControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(controlMarkerUI);

      //### Add a button on Google Maps ...
      var controlTrashUI = document.createElement('DIV');
      controlTrashUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      controlTrashUI.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://localhost/trash.png)";
      controlTrashUI.style.height = '28px';
      controlTrashUI.style.width = '25px';
      controlTrashUI.style.top = '11px';
      controlTrashUI.style.left = '150px';
      controlTrashUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
      //myLocationControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(controlTrashUI);
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<PUT_YOUR_API-HERE>&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The map result is the follow

[image]

In my code the styles for the two buttons, marker and trash, are set in a way that shoud be aside the "Satellite" button in this manner

[image]

Why my style settings are not kept?

Suggestions / examples?

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer, not 100% if this is what you are looking for but here is the modified code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {

      var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

      // Create a div to hold the control.
      var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

      //### Add a button on Google Maps ...
      var controlMarkerUI = document.createElement('div');
      controlMarkerUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      controlMarkerUI.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      controlMarkerUI.style.height = '28px';
      controlMarkerUI.style.width = '25px';
      controlMarkerUI.style.marginLeft = '10px';
      controlMarkerUI.style.marginTop = '10px';
      controlMarkerUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
      controlDiv.appendChild(controlMarkerUI);


      //### Add a button on Google Maps ...
      var controlTrashUI = document.createElement('div');
      controlTrashUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      controlTrashUI.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      controlTrashUI.style.height = '28px';
      controlTrashUI.style.width = '25px';
      controlTrashUI.style.marginLeft = '60px';
      controlTrashUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
      controlMarkerUI.appendChild(controlTrashUI);

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(controlDiv);

}

</script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<PUT KEY 
 HEREEEE>&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you will have to change your logos back to your localhost I think this
is the best way to do what you want. Don't forget your API key!!

output:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGgH4.png)